# swirl load fails due to missing RCurl package

Tags: r, rcurl, swirl

I got the below error message when I run the swirl in Rstudio:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’ in loadNamespace(j
>   <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there
>   is no package called ‘RCurl’

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: How did you originally install it? Did you update any packages recently? It says it can't find the `RCurl` package so I would just try installing that manually and see what happens: `install.packages("RCurl")`

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, yes i updated packages and R and I did install RCurl separately too, but it returns "configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/94/3r9mjrqs0_b8jrmdth8f2mc40000gn/T/Rtmpk5scTK/R.INSTALLe4210075679/RCurl':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’

* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/RCurl’

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status"

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2 hours of installing decencies manually I solved mu problem by clicking on "Packages" then to "Install"